# Retrieve uploaded and tagged photos at once

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the [`FB.api`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/) to retrieve users images for my app. According to Facebook Graph API documentation we can  [obtain user images](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) with:

```
me/photos // tagged only
me/photos/uploaded // uploaded only
me/photos?type=uploaded // uploaded only
```

But I would like to retrieve a paginated view of every photo in the user profile. Both uploaded and tagged photos should be returned at once.

I've tried

```
me/photos/type=uploaded,tagged&limit=25
```

Which obviously does not work, failing with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) type must be one of the following values: tagged, uploaded", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is there a way to obtain a complete list of user pictures (including both tagged and uploaded pictures)?